# pythonでwebサーバーを起動させたいのですが上手くいきません。

Tags: python, python3

表記の件につきましてご教授ください。
ターミナル上で以下のコードを実行したのですがエラーが返ってきました。

【コード】
$ python -m http.server

【エラー】
/usr/bin/python: No module named http

【試したこと】
ポート番号を入れて試しましたが上手くいきませんでした。
以下に記します。

$ python -m http.server 8000

【エラー】
/usr/bin/python: No module named http

---

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `python --version` で表示されるPythonのバージョンはなんですか? Python 3.xならhttp.serverモジュールは標準で含まれているはずですので、もしかしたらお使いのバージョンは2.xかもしれません。もしそうだったら`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`が使えると思います。

Comment: python3を使っています。
orangecatさまのコメントを見て以下のコードで試したところ上手くいきました。ありがとうございました。

【コード】
$ python3 -m http.server

Comment: @orangecat さん、有意義なコメントありがとうございました。よろしければ回答としても投稿して頂けると嬉しいです ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@nekketsuuu さんの勧めに従い回答としても投稿しておきます。]

`python --version` でPythonのバージョンを調べてください。
Python 3.xならhttp.serverモジュールが標準で含まれているはずですので、もしかしたらお使いのバージョンは2.xかもしれません。
Python 2.xだったら`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`が使えます。